# penis erection problems is this due to smoking

Tags: injury, smoking

### If this is not right place to ask this question comment me i will delete this question

Am just `22` and I use to puff 3-4 **cigarettes** a day and monthly average **`1000ml beer`**
and i ride CBR 150cc bike

```
My problem is my cock erection is weak compared at age of 18
```

**`Since I started to smoke at age of 19`** I feel this is because of **smoking and drinking**

**can any body help me**

What is problem for this or what all i should do

### **`To quit smoking I use to chew black pepper whenever I feel smoking`** so that I can control myself

Comment: This could (probably) be more appropriate on [health.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health), but that site is still just a proposal.

Comment: This is not appropriate for this site since it refers to a medical issue.

Comment: Is this in any way related to fitness or exercising?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD after reading this only i posted this *Physical Fitness Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers, and those providing* **health-related needs** i asked because smokin is injuries to health and this will be also a  issue **right**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smoking can definitely be the cause of your erectile dysfunction problems.  Nicotine, which is found in cigarettes, is a *vasoconstrictor*, which is a type of drug that causes your blood vessels to shrink.  When a male erection is forming, the blood vessels inside the penis need to widen so they can become gorged with blood.  Smoking too many cigarettes could potentially interfere with this.

If cigarettes are the cause of your problem, you could try quitting.  You could also try taking a drug like Viagra of Cialis.

Comment: Sure, smoking "can be" the cause. So can stress, poor nutrition, injury, disease, any number of causes.

Comment: i quitted smoking what all i should do to get back blood vessels to normal or any food items that make my blood vessels strong